# How to output a live broadcast with object detection Yolov8. I get an error: [h264 @ 000001fd8b8cf040] error while decoding MB 88 11, bytestream -9

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, h.264, rtsp

I'm trying to connect the Yolov8 object detection model to live streaming. i'm using Opencv in Python. below is the code. The script runs, works fine for a couple minutes, then gives the following errors:

```
[h264 @ 0000021fec1f0040] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 33 32
[h264 @ 0000021fec1f0040] error while decoding MB 33 32, bytestream 145146
[h264 @ 0000021fec56f300] error while decoding MB 56 14, bytestream -5.
```

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load the YOLOv8 model
 model = YOLO(r'...\best.pt')

# Open the video file
video_path = "rtsp://..."
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Loop through the video frames
while cap.isOpened():

    success, frame = cap.read()

    if success:
    
        results = model.track(frame, persist=True)

    
        annotated_frame = results[0].plot()

    
        cv2.imshow("Palka", annotated_frame)
```

I thought it was a coding problem, but the script works and recognizes the items, but then it gives an error

Comment: [mre] required. figure out whether loading and running the model is required. substitute with other delay or no delay at all.

Comment: @ИгорьДружелюбов H.264 is a video format. The error is from getting some corrupt video frame data. Your code can only work around the problem. **Possible Solution:** What happens if you add a `if not success:` handler that will first stop/release the CV capture and then secondly it re-connects CV back to that livestream? .. Also it is possible that you actually only need to capture and analyze **one frame for each one second** and still get a correct result for object detection. You will get less errors if you capture less frequently. So you try using a Timer not a While loop. Still got error?

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for the help, but there is still a bug tried your 2 options

Comment: @ИгорьДружелюбов Then you have the worst live stream data. **(1)** Since the error comes from `cap.read()` you can only do an If/Else statement to check if `success` was `true`, where if it is `false` then you have to stop and reconnect before reading, thus skipping the bad frame... but for you this option doesn't work.  **(2)** When using the Timer option, you can also add a `Try` statement to first "test read" the frame (without crashing the main app) and see an error is reported, if yes to getting an error then the Timer does not do any second "actual" read (outside of `Try`) at this tick.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using this code:

```
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO(r'best.pt')
results = model.track(source='rtsp:...', show=True)
video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(results)

while True:
    ret, frame = video_cap.read()
    model.cpu()

    if not ret:
        break

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

video_cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But now I can't display the shapes on the screen with this code:

```
annotated_frame = results[0].plot()
cv2.rectangle(annotated_frame, (100, 900), (600, 700), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.rectangle(annotated_frame, (1250, 710), (1800, 900), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?